# How to set `underline` of text in Konva?

Tags: javascript, konvajs

I am using [`Konvajs`](https://github.com/konvajs/konva) and I have problem with `Text`.
I want to draw `underline` of `Text`. Like `text-decoration: underline` in css.

Is there any way to draw `underline`?

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution here. [KonvaJS - Underline text decoration](https://github.com/konvajs/konva/issues/189)
And it's working as expected now.

[image]